# Ruby Viewpoint Gem 1.27

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to send a message with the Viewpoint Ruby Gem to an EWS endpoint.  I am only  able to send the message in plain text format.  How can I send it in html format?

Here is the code:

```
Viewpoint::EWS::EWS.endpoint=Conf.application.email.ews.endpoint
Viewpoint::EWS::EWS.set_auth(Conf.application.email.ews.username,Conf.application.email.ews.password)
Viewpoint::EWS::Message.send(options[:subject],msg_str,to_addresses)
```

I see that there is a text_only "instance" method, but am not able to initialize an instance of a message object to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Trick is to set body_type. Note: This example is derived from the example at https://github.com/zenchild/Viewpoint based on v1.0beta.

```
require 'viewpoint'
include Viewpoint::EWS

endpoint = 'https://example.com/ews/Exchange.asmx'
user = 'username'
pass = 'password'

cli = Viewpoint::EWSClient.new endpoint, user, pass
cli.send_message do |m|
  m.subject = "Test"
  m.body    = "<html><body><strong>Test</strong> message</body></html>"
  m.body_type = 'HTML'
  m.to_recipients << 'test@example.com'
end
```